# Random process and statistics

Tags: random-functions

Im trying to solve this and im really having trouble with understanding how to do this
lets say given two random variables x1,x2 that are independent and uniformly distributed between 0 and 1
we are given the next random process
y = ln(1/x1)
z = sqrt(y)
w1 = ln(1/x1), w2 = ln(1/x2) -> w=w1+w2

for each of these i need to calculate the CDF
can anyone explain the process of how to get a solution for this?

Comment: Could you format you're question with mathjax?

Comment: Hint: begin with $P(Z \leq z)$ and manipulate.

Comment: but to do that i need to assume a y which is dependent on x, and because of the connection of y=ln(1/x1) i get that for x between 0 and 1 i get a y that is between negative infinity and 0, this is where im stuck

Comment: i came to a conclusion that cdf of y is 1-e^-y for any value of y>0, am i even in the right direction?